# VBA Only to return Unique Values of Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below function that performs a vlookup and returns multiple values in one cell, I now want it to only return unique values but still multiple results and I cant seem to work it out!

```
Function VLookupAll(ByVal lookup_value As String, _
                    ByVal lookup_column As range, _
                    ByVal return_value_column As Long, _
                    Optional seperator As String = ", ") As String

Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

For i = 1 To lookup_column.Rows.count
    If Len(lookup_column(i, 1).text) <> 0 Then
        If lookup_column(i, 1).text = lookup_value Then
            result = result & (lookup_column(i).offset(0, return_value_column).text & seperator)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

VLookupAll = result

End Function
```

Comment: Instead of appending your results to a string `result = result &  …` put them into a dictionary (only unique entries can exist) and convert that into a string later. There are plenty of examples how to use a dictionary to make values unique. The other option is to test with `instr` if the looked up value is already in the `result` string, and only add it if it is not. Give that a try. I would prefer the dictionary solution.

Comment: In O365 you can do something similar with formuias. If not, I would suggest a VBA method using VBA arrays and, to avoid duplicates, use either a dictionary, collection or arrayList object to gather the results, before combining them into a string. I think you will find the vbaArray methods to be much faster than vlookup on a worksheet range. Even using Range.Find would be faster.